# "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen" when converting a file to a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, file, text, directory

I tried to read a text file like so:

```
file = File.read(record.file)
```

and received the error `no implicit conversion of Paperclip::Attachment into String`

So I appended to_s on the end to convert it to a string:

```
text = File.read(record.file.to_s)
```

and I received the error `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

I know for a fact that this file and directory exist because I have an anchor tag that redirects to the file, and this is unaffected by appending to_s on the end.

I tried manually pasting in the file path but I received the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message “no implicit conversion of Paperclip::Attachment into String” is telling you that `File.read` expects a string, but the argument that you passed in (`record.file`) was a `Paperclip::Attachment`. What you need is a way to get the path associated with that attachment object.

Looking at the source code for `Paperclip::Attachment`, I see that [its `to_s` method returns a URL](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L183-L186). Passing a URL to `File.read` gives a file not found error because `File.read` expects a path. In short, you’re passing `file://foo/bar` to a method that expects just `/foo/bar`.

I notice that [the `path` method returns a path on the file system](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L162-L169) (unless the attachment is stored on S3), so try this:

`file = File.read(record.file.path)`